# Markdown editing help doesn't mention ruby

Tags: discussion, markdown

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help doesn't mention how to do ruby. Is this something that can be changed per stack exchange, or is it fixed for all sites?

Comment: Although I see why it is not mentioned in the help (ruby is implemented in a very different way from other formatting), it would be much better if it were listed in the help.

Comment: Is it not part of the customized markdown?

Comment: No, the ruby syntax is not part of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) but a JLU extension to Markdown.  This is why it is not implemented in the other websites in the Stack Exchange network, and why it is not listed in the help.  However, clearly it should be listed in the help.